# Hacer una consulta con un arreglo y ejecutar una condicion dependiendo del numero de resultados verdaderos

Tags: php, mysql, array, bucle-for

el asunto es que el usuario mete en un input estos 3 ID, que yo meto en un arreglo para después hacer una consulta de esos 3 registros y si los 3 tienen status En Bodega ejecutara una función donde actualizare el status de los 3 a Salida Total, pero si uno ya tiene Salida Total, no debe ejecutar la actualización de ninguno de los registros y notificarle al usuario por un ALERT, el problema es que al hacer el bucle en la consulta... les muestro... donde

Para mayor contexto

tabla en BD

| ID | status |
| --- | --- |
| 2072 | En Bodega |
| 2073 | Salida Total |
| 2074 | En Bodega |

```
$cadena = $_REQUEST['entrys'];     *----EN EL REQUEST TRAIGO 2072,2073,2074---* 
$separador = ",";
$separada = explode($separador, $cadena);
$arrlength = count($separada);
for($x = 0; $x < $arrlength; $x++)

{
  $operativo = mysqli_query($connection,"SELECT * FROM entrada WHERE status = 'Salida Total' AND ID = '$separada[$x]'");
      
      if(mysqli_num_rows($operativo) > 0)

        {

            echo "<script language='JavaScript'> 
            <!--
            alert('**NO** SE PUEDE REALIZAR LA SALIDA MULTIPLE, UNO DE LOS REGISTRO 
            YA TIENE SU SALIDA TOTAL POR FAVOR VERIFICA');
            history.back();
            //-->
            </script>";

        }

     else
   
        {               
                        $aerosmith= "UPDATE entrada SET 
                        status='Salida Total',
                        CIA_Transportista='".$_REQUEST["transporte"]."',
                        Nombre_Chofer='".$_REQUEST["chofer"]."',
                        Fecha_Salida='".$_REQUEST["fexit"]."',
                        hora_salida='".$_REQUEST["texit"]."'
                
                        WHERE 
            
                        entrada.ID='$separada[$x]'";
            
                        mysqli_query($connection,$aerosmith) or die('La consulta fallo '.mysqli_error());
                    
            echo "<script language='JavaScript'> 
                        <!--
                        alert('SE GENERO LA SALIDA MULTIPLE CON EXITO');
                        pagina = 'salida_multiple.php';
                        document.location = (pagina);
                        //-->
                   </script>";
        }
}
```

OK ahora bien, el detalle es tomando en cuenta la pequeña tabla que les compartí, ejecutarse la consulta con el bucle revisa primero el registro 2072 y como es  resultado es 0 lo actualiza, luego vuelve a hacer la consulta pero ahora con el registro 2073 y como ese dara resultado mayor a 0, no lo actuliza y me manda ALERT de que no lo actualizara, y luego con el ultimo 2074 manda que no lo registrara porque es 0

lo que requiero es que si alguno de los registros del arreglo al consultarlos tiene Salida Total ( o en su defecto mayor que 0) NO ACTUALICE NADA NINGUNO DE LOS IDs QUE TRAIGO EN EL ARREGLO Y ME AVISE, o de lo contrario si ninguno tiene Salida Total o En Bodega o Salida Parcial (o es igual a 0) entonces SI ACTUALICE TODOS LOS IDs

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Si no te he entendido mal, lo que quieres es eliminar el bucle for y actualizar todos los registros a la vez. Bastaría unos cambios mínimos en las consultas select y update para que afectaran a todos los registros a la vez incluyendo una clausula IN.

Aplicando los cambios a tu código quedaría

```
$listaIds = $_REQUEST['entrys'];     
$selectResult = mysqli_query($connection, 
    "SELECT * FROM entrada WHERE status = 'Salida Total' AND ID IN (".$listaIds.")");
      
if (mysqli_num_rows($selectResult) > 0) {

    echo "<script language='JavaScript'> 
    <!--
        alert('**NO** SE PUEDE REALIZAR LA SALIDA MULTIPLE, UNO DE LOS REGISTRO 
            YA TIENE SU SALIDA TOTAL POR FAVOR VERIFICA');
        history.back();
    //-->
    </script>";

} else {               
    $updateQuery = 
       "UPDATE entrada SET status='Salida Total',
                           CIA_Transportista='".$_REQUEST["transporte"]."',
                           Nombre_Chofer='".$_REQUEST["chofer"]."',
                           Fecha_Salida='".$_REQUEST["fexit"]."',
                            hora_salida='".$_REQUEST["texit"]."'
                
        WHERE entrada.ID IN (".$listaIds.")";
            
        mysqli_query($connection, $updateQuery) or die('La consulta fallo '.mysqli_error());
                    
        echo "<script language='JavaScript'> 
        <!--
             alert('SE GENERO LA SALIDA MULTIPLE CON EXITO');
             pagina = 'salida_multiple.php';
             document.location = (pagina);
        //-->
        </script>";
}
```

Puedes optimizar un poco la consulta de SELECT de forma que no te traiga todos los datos de los registros, ya que no los usas para nada a continuación, para que te realice un conteo únicamente.

```
$listaIds = $_REQUEST['entrys'];
$selectResult = mysqli_query($connection, 
  "SELECT COUNT(*) as total 
   FROM entrada WHERE status = 'Salida Total' AND ID IN (".$listaIds.")");
$data = mysqli_fetch_assoc($selectResult);
Stotal = $data['total'];

if ($total > 0) {
...
} else {
...
}
```

Puede que haya algún error de sintaxis en el código que he puesto, ya que no lo he ejecutado, pero esa es la idea.

Dos apuntes finales:
1 - Échale un ojo al concepto de [PreparedStatement](https://www.php.net/manual/es/mysqli.prepare.php) para evitar inyecciones SQL.
2 - Intenta que los nombres de tus variables sean significativos. Lo de $aerosmith puede que no le haga tanta gracia al que tenga que arreglar o modificar tu código de urgencia.

Comment: Muchas Gracias @RubioRic por el apoyo, me solucionaste el problema al 100% y tomare en cuenta los puntos finales, por cierto ya no existe la variable $aerosmith, ya la renombramos por un nombre mas sugerente

Answer (score 1):

He reproducido el problema y hay muchas maneras de resolverlo. El asunto es que al momento de recorrer el array de los 3 productos  el sistema no sabe que en estado se encuentras los demás registros.

Tendría que crear un contador de errores  por defecto con valor 0  `$errores = 0;`
Tabiem un array con los updates  `$updates = [];`

Luego en el ciclo `for`  preguntar  si el producto tiene salida, si la tiene `$errores ++;` y independiente mente de ese `if`  guardar los updates en el array `$updates`

A fuera del ciclo `for` pregunta si `$errores == 0` se actualizan los registros,  si no muestras el error.

El código quedara así :

```html
$cadena = $_REQUEST['entrys'];     *----EN EL REQUEST TRAIGO 2072,2073,2074---* 
$separador = ",";
$separada = explode($separador, $cadena);
$arrlength = count($separada);

$errores = 0 ;
$updates =[] ;
for($x = 0; $x < $arrlength; $x++)

  $operativo = mysqli_query($connection,"SELECT * FROM entrada WHERE status = 'Salida Total' AND ID = '$separada[$x]'");
      
      if(mysqli_num_rows($operativo) > 0){
          $errores ++ ;
        }else{               
            $aerosmith= "UPDATE entrada SET 
                         status='Salida Total',
                         CIA_Transportista='".$_REQUEST["transporte"]."',
                         Nombre_Chofer='".$_REQUEST["chofer"]."',
                         Fecha_Salida='".$_REQUEST["fexit"]."',
                         hora_salida='".$_REQUEST["texit"]."'
                         WHERE 
                         entrada.ID='$separada[$x]'";
            $updates[] = $aerosmith;
        }
}



if($errores == 0){
    foreach($updates as $key => $value){
        mysqli_query($connection,$value) or die('La consulta fallo '.mysqli_error());
    }
                
    echo "<script language='JavaScript'> 
                <!--
                alert('SE GENERO LA SALIDA MULTIPLE CON EXITO');
                pagina = 'salida_multiple.php';
                document.location = (pagina);
                //-->
           </script>";

}else{
    echo "<script language='JavaScript'> 
    <!--
    alert('**NO** SE PUEDE REALIZAR LA SALIDA MULTIPLE, UNO DE LOS REGISTRO 
    YA TIENE SU SALIDA TOTAL POR FAVOR VERIFICA');
    history.back();
    //-->
    </script>";
}
```

Comment: Muchas Gracias @Wilfredo Alemán por el apoyo, sin querer me ayudaste a resolver otro problema que tenia con otras partes de mi Desarrollos, Muchas Gracias !